# Deploy xamarin app on real iphone for debug

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to deploy a xamarin forms app for debug to my physical Iphone.

On previous versions, I just had to plug the iphone to the mac and the deployment target was automatically switched to the real device.
Since the last update no change when I plug the phone no change to the deployment target, I still have "device" target and it is impossible to deploy to the real device using this configuration... (visual studio for mac 7.4.2 and visual studio 15.6.7)

Was there a change on the behavior of the deployment? can't find any informations ATM...

Thank you

Comment: Can your visual studio for mac deploy on a real device?

Comment: Today, I could repair the connexion between the mac and my developping computer, the iphone simulator was prompted on my pc. But when I plug a physical iphone, he is not listed in visual studio for mac in the device part...

Comment: Try to check your project's deploy target version in the info.plist. Is it higher than your device's os version?

Comment: Deployment target is 8.0 and I put an 11.2.6 iphone